# MySQL error: Unknown column in '1' in `where clause`

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a two  table called student and book.
student table having 3 column studentid,name,coursename;
book table having 4 column student id,name ,coursename,bookname,

I am trying to create a query that will get student id from book table and comapare with student table and if id match with that table the value will get printed but  I am getting an error "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'"

```
  String abc=txt1.getText();
  String sql;
  sql = "select * from `student` where studentid = `"+abc+"`";
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should be using a `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters. You also need to tell us what type `studentid` is (in the database). And your `String` looks really funky the way you've posted it.

Comment: You're putting the value of `abc` in backticks, which makes it a column name, not a string.